# accessing all attributes when parsing xml using data.zip

Tags: xml, clojure

I'm successfully using the Clojure [data.zip](http://clojure.github.io/data.zip/) library to navigate xml and extract the values I want, however it would be convenient if I could extract all of an element's attributes at once. I'm currently stuck extracting them one by one with the `attr` function. For example:

`(xml1-> article :meta (xml/attr :attr1))`

and then again for `:attr2` and then `:attr3` and so on. What would be great would be something like:

`(xml1-> article :meta :attrs)`

returning the map of available attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xml1->` returns a zipper `loc` or `nil` so you can create your own function that returns all attributes:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip])
(defn attrs [loc]
  (when (zip/branch? loc) (-> loc zip/node :attrs)))
```

This is almost exactly the same what the `attr` function does [here](https://github.com/clojure/data.zip/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/zip/xml.clj#L20).

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I looked at the source code for `attr` and did the exact same thing you've done however it didn't work (I was getting some sort of very unclojure-like xml node object) but I'll try again tonight with your suggestion.

Comment: ah - I can see where I was going wrong now. Thanks for the help.